# regex to remove comma and space inside of square brackets

Tags: java, regex

Hello I have a file that looks like this:

```
year.", [229, 338], null, [1144, 2371]
year....", null, null, [812]
year:, null, null, [1019, 1028, 2463]
year;, null, [164], [1052]
```

This what I would like the file to look like

```
year.", 229:338, , 1144:2371
year....", , , 812
year:, , , 1019:1028:2463
year;, , 164, 1052
```

I have tried `.replaceAll(",[?=[^()]*\\]]",":") but this is just replacing all of the commas not the ones inside of the bracket.`

Comment: to simplify should it just be a number followed by a comma that needs replacing?

Comment: good observation. the values inside the brackets are always numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to

- remove all `null`s
- replace `number, number, number` with `number:number:number`, in other words replace each `,` which has digit before it with `:`
- remove `[` and `]`

Demo:

```
String input = 
        "year.\", [229, 338], null, [1144, 2371]\r\n" + 
        "year....\", null, null, [812]\r\n" + 
        "year:, null, null, [1019, 1028, 2463]\r\n" + 
        "year;, null, [164], [1052]";

String expected = 
        "year.\", 229:338, , 1144:2371\r\n" + 
        "year....\", , , 812\r\n" + 
        "year:, , , 1019:1028:2463\r\n" + 
        "year;, , 164, 1052";

input = input.replace("null", "")
             .replaceAll("(?<=\\d), ", ":")
             .replaceAll("\\[|\\]", "");

System.out.println(input.equals(expected));
```

Output: `true`.

Comment: the last one, since we are matching a single char for sure, character set is more handy: `"[][]"`. such that it matches either bracket.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr `[][]` doesn't mean what you think it does. Your regex represents two empty character class/sets. `]` is special character inside character class which represents its end. We would need to escape each of `[` and `]` inside character class if we would want them to represent literals. In my version I don't even need to escape `]` since it can't represent end of character set/class because there was no properly opened one, but I like to escape it for clarity.

Comment: nope. you are 50% percent right. in a char set, if `]` appears immediately after `[`, it means the character itself, without having to escape. the same as `[`. if it shows up in a char set, it means the character itself. https://regex101.com/r/JNSAIb/1

Comment: in your version, if you didn't escape, you gave a wrong one. it would match a pipe char, only.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr Oh, OK I was wrong. But unfortunately you are also not entirely correct. It is true character set can't be empty (I totally missed that), but in Java your regex will also not work, since `[` will be considered as start of another inner character set. What we could use here is `"[]][]]"` but IMO mine regex is simpler.

Comment: ok. that means java re engine is not totally pcre compliant then. good to know some details.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr True, here is demo confirming it: https://ideone.com/fzHf6i